# Some[Seq[X]] does not conform to the expected type Option[Seq[X]]

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and I get the compile time error:

> Expression of type Some[Seq[String]] does not conform to the expected type Option[Seq[String]]

and this the line in the code

```
val enabledCipherSuites : Option[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[String]] = Some(Seq("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"))
```

I looked into the Option class source code but can't figure out why Some of a sequence is not Option of Sequence.

Let me know why. Thanks

Edit 1 : I need to explicitly specify that my sequence is immutable as required later in the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the default `Seq` you are importing is actually something else, namely `scala.collection.Seq`. This is defined in `scala.Predef`, the standard set of imports:

```
type Seq[+A] = scala.collection.Seq[A]
val Seq = scala.collection.Seq
```

Now the default variance of `Option` would work the other way around.

```
val enabledCipherSuites : Option[Seq[String]] = Some(scala.collection.immutable.Seq("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"))
```

This is because `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` extends `scala.collection.Seq`, but obviously not the other way around. The first scenario works because `Option` is covariant in its type parameter, so you for any `B <: A`, `Option[B]` is a subtype of `Option[A]`.

Your case is the opposite, you have `immutable.Seq[A] <:< collection.Seq[A]`, but you're expecting an `Option[collection.Seq[A]]` to be a subtype of `Option[immutable.Seq[A]]`, which is not true, only the reverse is true.

The Predef import combined with variance is the reason for confusion here.